# Probability questions.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The following experiment is used to check a person who claims to have powers of mental telepathy. Six cards are numbered 1 through 6. Seat the person being tested on one side of a screen and a person who will select a card on the other side. The person with the cards shuffles them, selects one at random, and turns it up. The person being tested "receives vibes" and tells which number he thinks is turned up. The card is replaced, and the process is repeated for a total of six times.

- $a)$
  Based on random chance alone, find the probability that the person being tested identifies all six numbers correctly.
- $b)$ Based on random chance alone, find the probability that the person being tested identifies all six numbers incorrectly.
- $c)$ Based on random chance alone, find the probability that the person being tested identifies at least one of the six numbers correctly.

I know this is a type of conditional probability problem but I have no idea how to start this. Please help me with some pointers.

Comment: @LeilaHatami And yet another useless edit to a 3+ years old question. Well done.

Comment: @Did Your Welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

The probability of guessing a particular one correctly is $\frac 1 6$

The probability of guessing two correctly is $(\frac 1 6)^2$ or $\frac 1 6 \times \frac 1 6$

The probability of guessing at least one correctly (just by chance) is $1-(\frac 5 6)^2$.
This is because the subject "did not guess wrong twice".

Using the first two rules, you should be able to get a and b.  The last one is needed for c.

Comment: Note that the 2nd and 3rd rules above refer to cases of two cards being drawn.